# Spliting row of table according to table data

Tags: javascript, html

It's making table with data 1 to 31 numbers in it. Now I want, as soon as a row is filled with seven numbers, it should automatically add a new row & insert numbers in that & it should continue till table finish. I mean first it will insert from  1 to 7, then next row should be added & data begins with 8 & after 15 a new row again started. Something like a calendar.

See the code snippet below.

```js
var myDays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
var tableHeader = "";
var tableData = "";
var tableRow = "";

for (j = 1; j < 32; j++) {
    tableData += "<td>" + j + "</td>";
}

document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = tableData;
```

```css
#days, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#days {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="days"></table>
```

Comment: You can put an `if` condition in your loop and perform the required logic there

Comment: Use the `%` modulus operator to test whether you've reached a multiple of 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an outer loop for controlling the rows, and an inner loop for adding each `<td>` element. You can control the values of elements in the inner loop by offsetting them based on a multiple of the index of the outer loop.

Basically, if `j` is the index of your inner loop, and `i` is the index of your outer loop, then take a multiple of `i` (in this case `i*7`) and offset the start of `j` by that. See code example below.

```js
var myDays = ["SUN", "MON", "TUE", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"];
var tableHeader = "";
var tableData = "";
var tableRow = "";

for (var i=0; i<32/7; i++) {
    var k = i * 7;
    tableData += "<tr>";

    for (var j = 1 + k; j <= 7 + k; j++) {
        if (j > 31) break;
        tableData += "<td>" + j + "</td>";
    }

    tableData += "</tr>";
}

document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = tableData;
```

```css
#days, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#days {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table id="days"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this answer

```
counter=0;
tableData+='<tr>';
            for(j=1; j<32; j++){
            if(counter==7)
            {
                tableData+='</tr>';
                counter=0;
            }
            tableData+= "<td>" + j + "</td>";
            ++counter;
        }
```